Ensure the token is verified in a React Native application before utilizing it
I want to set up an authentication system with Google using @react-native-google-signin/google-signin.
The login works well with the authorization prompt.
My problem is that if the token has expired or been revoked by the user, the application continues to authenticate the user with the token stored in AsyncStorage.
So, what I want to do is verify if the token is valid or not. If it is valid, we use it to authenticate the user when the application starts; if not, we log the user out.
I tried using Axios to refetch the token, but it didn't work.
I also tried with Firebase Auth import auth, {firebase} from '@react-native-firebase/auth', but that didn't work either, and I'm not sure if it's the right approach.
import {jwtDecode} from 'jwt-decode';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
import React, {ReactNode, useEffect, useState, useCallback} from 'react';
import AuthContext from './AuthContext';
import {
  AccessToken,
  LoginManager,
  GraphRequestCallback,
} from 'react-native-fbsdk-next';
import {
  BatchRequestResultType,
  FacebookCallbackType,
} from '@/types/FacebookTypes';
import {fetchFacebookUserInfo} from '@/utils/FacebookUtiles';
import {
  GoogleSignin,
  isErrorWithCode,
  statusCodes,
} from '@react-native-google-signin/google-signin';
import auth, {firebase} from '@react-native-firebase/auth';
import {WEB_CLIENT_ID} from '@/constants/GoogleType';

type Props = {
  children: ReactNode;
};

GoogleSignin.configure({
  webClientId: WEB_CLIENT_ID,
});

export const AuthProvider: React.FC<Props> = ({children}) => {
  const [userToken, setUserToken] = useState<string | null>(null);
  const [userInfo, setUserInfo] = useState<any>(null);
  const [tokenType, setTokenType] = useState<string | null>(null);

  const storeToken = async (token: string, type: string) => {
    try {
      await AsyncStorage.setItem('@user_token', token);
      await AsyncStorage.setItem('@token_type', type);
      setUserToken(token);
      setTokenType(type);
      console.log('Stored token and type:', token, type);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Failed to store token and type:', error);
    }
  };

  const loginFacebook = async () => {
    try {
      const result = await LoginManager.logInWithPermissions([
        'public_profile',
        'email',
      ]);
      if (result.isCancelled) {
        throw new Error('User cancelled the login process');
      }

      const data = await AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();
      if (!data) {
        throw new Error('Something went wrong obtaining access token');
      }

      const token = data.accessToken.toString();
      await storeToken(token, 'facebook');
      fetchFacebookUserInfo({token, callback: handleFacebookCallback});
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  const loginGoogle = async () => {
    try {
      await GoogleSignin.hasPlayServices({showPlayServicesUpdateDialog: true});
      const {idToken} = await GoogleSignin.signIn();

      const googleCredential = auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(idToken);
      await auth().signInWithCredential(googleCredential);

      const currentUser = auth().currentUser;
      console.log('currentUser', currentUser);
      if (currentUser) {
        const token = await currentUser.getIdToken(true);
        await storeToken(token, 'google');
        fetchGoogleUserInfo(token);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      if (isErrorWithCode(error)) {
        switch (error.code) {
          case statusCodes.SIGN_IN_CANCELLED:
            console.log('User cancelled the login flow');
            break;
          case statusCodes.IN_PROGRESS:
            console.log('Operation (e.g., sign in) already in progress');
            break;
          case statusCodes.PLAY_SERVICES_NOT_AVAILABLE:
            console.log('Play services not available or outdated');
            break;
          default:
            console.log('Some other error happened', error);
        }
      }
    }
  };

  const loginWithToken = async (
    token: string,
    fetchUserInfoFunc: (token: string) => Promise<void>,
  ) => {
    setUserToken(token);
    await AsyncStorage.setItem('@user_token', token);
    fetchUserInfoFunc(token);
  };

  const handleFacebookCallback: GraphRequestCallback = async (
    error,
    result,
  ) => {
    if (error) {
      const fbError = error as FacebookCallbackType;
      if (fbError && fbError.batchRequestResult) {
        try {
          const parsedBatchResult = JSON.parse(
            fbError.batchRequestResult,
          ) as BatchRequestResultType;

          const errorCode = parsedBatchResult.error?.code;
          if (errorCode === 190) {
            setUserInfo(null);
            setUserToken(null);
            await AsyncStorage.removeItem('@user_token');
            await AsyncStorage.removeItem('@token_type');
          }
        } catch (parseError) {
          console.error('Failed to parse batchRequestResult:', parseError);
        }
      }
    } else if (result) {
      setUserInfo(result);
    }
  };

  const fetchGoogleUserInfo = async (token: string) => {
    console.log('fetchGoogleUserInfo', token);
    try {
      const decoded = jwtDecode(token);
      console.log('decoded', decoded);

      await GoogleSignin.hasPlayServices({showPlayServicesUpdateDialog: false});

      // Récupérer silencieusement les informations de l'utilisateur
      const {user} = await GoogleSignin.signInSilently();

      console.log('user', user);

      if (user) {
        setUserInfo(user);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      if (isErrorWithCode(error)) {
        switch (error.code) {
          case statusCodes.SIGN_IN_CANCELLED:
            setUserToken(null);
            console.log('User cancelled the login flow');
            break;
          case statusCodes.IN_PROGRESS:
            console.log('Operation (e.g., sign in) already in progress');
            break;
          case statusCodes.PLAY_SERVICES_NOT_AVAILABLE:
            console.log('Play services not available or outdated');
            break;
          case statusCodes.SIGN_IN_REQUIRED:
            setUserToken(null);
            console.log('User has not signed in yet');
            break;
          default:
            console.log('Some other error happened', error);
        }
      }
    }
  };

  const fetchCredentialsUserInfo = async (token: string) => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(`https://your-api.com/userinfo`, {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
        },
      });
      const data = await response.json();
      setUserInfo(data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Failed to fetch user info', error);
    }
  };

  const logout = async () => {
    setUserToken(null);
    setUserInfo(null);
    setTokenType(null);
    await AsyncStorage.removeItem('@user_token');
    await AsyncStorage.removeItem('@token_type');
  };

  const fetchUserInfo = useCallback(
    async (token: string) => {
      if (!userInfo && token) {
        if (tokenType === 'facebook') {
          fetchFacebookUserInfo({token, callback: handleFacebookCallback});
        } else if (tokenType === 'google') {
          console.log('Calling fetchGoogleUserInfo');
          fetchGoogleUserInfo(token);
        }
      }
    },
    [tokenType, userInfo],
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchStoredToken = async () => {
      try {
        const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@user_token');
        const type = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@token_type');

        if (token && type) {
          setUserToken(token);
          setTokenType(type);
          fetchUserInfo(token);
        } else {
          setUserInfo(null);
          setUserToken(null);
          setTokenType(null);
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Failed to fetch stored token and type:', error);
      }
    };

    fetchStoredToken();
  }, [fetchUserInfo]);

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider
      value={{
        userToken,
        userInfo,
        loginFacebook,
        loginGoogle,
        loginCredentials: (token: string) =>
          loginWithToken(token, fetchCredentialsUserInfo),
        logout,
      }}>
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};

